# Layout design in android having TextView with image

Tags: android

how can i mange Textview in layout.? please help me..

how can i set textview and border then again textview.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use two compound TextViews: Just create a horizontal LinearLayout, and add a TextView with drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_location" and another one with drawableLeft="@drawable/line_vertical" as children.
For both, a drawablePadding="8dp" or whatever you like best

Comment: hello ... its working...but Formatting of the textview as like Gender, Mobile NO... is not vertically equal.

Comment: Maybe the "gender" and "mobile_no" icons have a different size? Please, make sure that all icons are same sized. You could scale them by code, but it would be an overkill...

Answer (score 1):

Just create a horizontal LinearLayout, and add an `ImageView`, a `TextView`, a View with width 2dp and height `match_parent`, and a `TextView` as children.

Either repeat that for every row, or use the recommended approach of using a `ListView` with the above mentioned layout as rows.

Comment: I'd use two compound TextViews: Just create a horizontal LinearLayout, and add a TextView with drawableLeft="@drawable/icon_location" and another one with drawableLeft="@drawable/line_vertical" as children. For both, a drawablePadding="8dp" or whatever you like best

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility.

Comment: Just to minimize the View count. ;)